# Joining tables selecting values that exist only in one table

Tags: sql, teradata-sql-assistant

I have two tables

```
A
ID age  
1   24
2   25
45  22

B 
Name school Surname
34  school1  141
1   school2  152
```

I want to select Surname from B only for those Names that are not in A. ID and name have the same meaning in the two tables, but different name.
I wrote

```
Select distinct bb.Surname
From B as bb 
Left outer join A as aa 
On bb.Name=aa.ID
```

But the number of rows is the same as an inner join between the two tables.
I have approximately 100000 rows, so I cannot check manually.
Do you spot failures in my approach?

The answer provided is not solving the issue as I am getting the same values as an inner join, so something is clearly  wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   select b.surname
   from tableb as b
   left join tablea as a on b.name=a.id
   where a.id is null
```

Comment: Can I ask you why you added the condition isnull? Adding this condition I have no rows

Comment: Also, it is weird because if I use left outer or left join I get exactly the same values as an inner join. I think there is something wrong ...

Comment: Based on your example   WITH A (ID,AGE)AS
(
  SELECT 1,24 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2,25 UNION ALL
  SELECT 45,22
),
B  (NAME,school,Surname)AS
(
  SELECT 34,'school1',141
    UNION ALL
  SELECT 1,'school2',152
)
SELECT BB.SURNAME
FROM B AS BB
LEFT JOIN  A AS AA ON BB.NAME=AA.ID
WHERE AA.ID IS NULL